# How to prove $\Delta w(x) = \Delta [(1 / 2 \pi) \int_{R^2}(\ln |x-y|-\ln |y|) \exp u(y) d y ] = \exp u(x)$ under the assumption that $u$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How to prove
$$\Delta w(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\Delta [\int_{R^2}(\ln |x-y|-\ln |y|) \exp u(y) d y ]= \exp u(x)$$
under the assumption that $u$ is bounded.

This looks like something about the foluma that
$$
u(x)=\frac{1}{n \omega_n} \int_{\Omega} \frac{\left(x_i-y_i\right) D_i u(y)}{|x-y|^n} d y
$$
where $\Omega$ is a n-dimensional bounded domain with $\omega_n$ being its area.

Comment: Thanks! I get it, I will go to read some lectures about the Green function for Laplace in $\mathbb{R}^2$.